# Refresh a div to shows new rating in Django using JQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, django, html

I’m new to django and can’t find the way to refresh only the div and that the div shows me current rating with stars. My idea is that user can see average rating and rate something by clicking on the star, and after the click I want stars to show new average rating without refreshing the whole page.

This is the div:

```
<div id="rating">
    <div class="movierating" id="o_{{ object.id }}">
        <span style="display:none;">{{ object.rating_vote.get_rating }}</span>
        {{ object.rating_vote.get_rating }}
    </div>
</div>
```

And javascript is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
         $('.movierating').each(function(index){
          $(this).raty({
            readOnly:  false,
            path: "{{ STATIC_URL }}images/",
            start: $(this).children("span:first").text(),
            click: function(score, evt) {
                var vote_url = "/rate/" + this.attr('id').substring(2) + "/" + score + "/";
                var div = this.attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                  url: vote_url,
                  success: function(){
                    alert('Vote successful!);
                $('#rating').load('#rating');
                  },
                });
            }
          });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

With this code

`$('#rating').load('#rating');`

I get the whole page into the div, and when I use

`$('#rating').load('# rating');`

I get only value without the stars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, copy the code inside the `<div id="rating"></div>` and save it to another file. Lets say,

**rating.html**

```
 <div class="movierating" id="o_{{ object.id }}">
    <span style="display:none;">{{ object.rating_vote.get_rating }}</span>
    {{ object.rating_vote.get_rating }}
</div>
```

Now in your page, it will be,

**your.html**

```
............
<div id="rating">
    {% include 'rating.html' %}
</div>
............
```

Then, create `new view` and `new url` for `rating.html`

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^rating/$', 'rating', name='rating'),
```

**views.py**

```
def rating(request):
    //rating object here

    return render(request, 'rating.html', {
        //call rating object variable here
    })
```

Finally, in your ajax

```
.........
$.ajax({
    url: vote_url,
    success: function(){
        alert('Vote successful!);
        $("#rating").load("/app_name/rating/");
    },
});
...........
```

Comment: one more question, how to send id from rated object (which object is rated) to a view?

Comment: in your ajax, you can define GET and data to pass the id to your view

Comment: I tried with $('#rating').load($.get("/rating/", {values: values})); where values is id, but the div isn't reloaded

Comment: No, that's not the correct way to pass a value. Put that in the ajax not in the rating load

Comment: if I use $('#rating').load($.get("/rating/", {values: values})); I don't get any error but it doesn't refresh and if I put $.get("/rating/", {values: values}) in ajax, I get 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, "Key 'values' not found in <QueryDict: {}>". I can't figure it out

Comment: i am following your solution but facing some problem...please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335106/django-include-can-not-find-template