# Django include can not find template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to include 'comment.html' into store.html and store.html extend base.html.

But Django is throwing error `comment.html (<class 'django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist'>)`

All templates are in the same Dir. `store.html` works fine and it is extending `base.html` properly without any problem.But when i included `comment.html` in `store.html` the error is thrown...
I have used `{% include "comment.html" %}` this to include `comment.html` into `store.html`

Dir tree where these files are located:
vaibhav@ubuntu:~/TRAC/bright-coupons/brightCoupons/brightCouponsApp$ tree
.

```
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── templates
│   ├── about.html
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── comment.html
│   ├── contact.html
│   ├── error.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index-var.html
│   ├── store.html
│   ├── stores.html
│   ├── submit-form.php
│   ├── support.html
│   └── tags.html
├── tests.py
├── views.py
```

Comment: Recheck the file names.

Comment: did..checked...in Django extend and include within same template is supported or not?

Comment: Yes, its is supported and should not be issue. What is your `{%extend%}` line?

Comment: {% extends "base.html" %}

Comment: It is very strange! not sure what the problem is!

Comment: Can you post more information about the exception page? And more code from your template? And maybe the fragment of your directory tree where are these files? :)

Comment: does comment.html has an extends statement ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that when you do include to you have to put the path relative to the root of the template dir. So if comment.html resides in TEMPLATE_BASE_DIR/app/comments.html you have to do

```
{% include "app/comments.html" %}
```

the paths is not relative to the location of the including template (since the including template could be a string for that matter...)

Comment: i have tried that by putting...but it is throwing same error..anyway `comment.html` is inside templates dir within my app and all other templates are also inside the templates dir...

Comment: in order to include template is there anything you need to specify inside the included template...i mean in comment.html is there anything need to be specified...

Comment: No, it can be anything that fits into the outer template.
Have you tried including base.html to see if you get the same error? (of course that wouldn't produce a sensible template though...)

Comment: Well then try copying comment.html to bla.html, and then try to include bla.html - or try deleting the file and recreating it...
(You need to isolete whether this is a problem with the file's content (doesn't make sense though), the file's path or the file itself...)

Comment: I did not understand it is including any other page but not comment.html....is their anything wrong with the syntax of comment.html please have a look at comment.html....here http://notepad.cc/hookeave51

Comment: actually i want this to refresh the particular div not the whole page ...on some certain event ....can you tell me is there any other way of doing that...

Comment: You'll need to use ajax for that - something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583534/refresh-div-element-generated-by-a-django-template